# Listar Registros en django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Hola a todos estoy tratando de listar los registros en una app que estoy haciendo, pero algun motivo no esta funcionando, aqui tes dejo el codigo.

```
"""Config Views"""

#Django
from django.shortcuts import render

# Modelo
from .models import Config


def contenedor(request):
    configuracion = Config.objects.all()
    context = {'configuracion': configuracion }
    return render(request,"administrador/menu.html", context)
```

```
  {% for configuracion in configuracion %}
            <span class="nav-link-text ms-1">{{ configuracion.modcont }}</span>
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: No muestra ni siquiera un registro? Da algun error?

Comment: Ya resolvi gracias en la plantilla no estaba poniendo el nombre del campo bien, jjja un error me imagino de tanto tiempo sentado delante de un monitor,